# Pygame using Python3 IN mac

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to install pygame with python3 i followed the instructions in this [link](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/macintosh?parent=index) but it is not working.can anyone help and i'm running macOS sierra

Comment: We probably need more information beyond "it is not working".
FYI, the current recommended install method is with pip:
> pip install pygame

Comment: for mac only pygame with python2 is supported

Comment: will pip install pygame work for installing pygame with python3?

Comment: Python 3 is supported just fine.  Depending on how you installed, pip3 is the python 3 installer.  The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris for the help

To install pygame with python3:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

To get image loading capability:

```
brew install libpng
```